# Logical trap in R topology

Tags: general-topology, compactness

We know that in metric spaces, Bolzano-Weierstrass (BW) (each infinite set owns a cluster point) and Borel-Lebesgue (BL) properties are equivalent, i.e. compactness and countably compactness are equivalent (and also sequential compactness).

In the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, the BW theorem is often written : "Any bounded infinite set has a cluster point". So according to the equivalence, we can say that in $\mathbb{R}$, "any bouded set verifies (BL)", which is not true because we know that only bounded **and closed** sets do...

Can you help me to find where I am wrong among this...?

EDIT : to be more precise, here is the wrong reasoning:

"In $\mathbb{R}$, the collection of all infinite bounded sets verifies the (BW) property; since this property is equivalent to the (BL) property and since this one means compactness, all infinite bounded sets is compact."

Answer (score 4):

A sequence of points in a bounded but not closed subset will have a cluster point in $\mathbb R$, but the cluster point may fail to be a member of the *subset* -- so it is *not* necessarily sequentially compact.

Comment: Thanks. But you do not show my mistake, you just confirm it ;)!

Comment: @Carrérond: Your mistake is that you're confusing "has a cluster point" with "_contains_ a cluster point".

Comment: Yes, I can feel the difference, that's what you explained in your answer and I do agree. For instance, $]0,1]$ has the cluster point $0$ but does not contain it. 
However, how that can be related to the initial question that I am reformulating here : "an infinite bounded set $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$ verifies the (BW) property; well, (BW) $\iff$ (BL) in metric spaces, so $E$ verifies the (BL) property; hence $E$ is compact"... ??

Comment: @Carrérond: It depends on what _exactly_ you consider "verifies the BW property" and "verifies the BL property" to mean. You will have to check with your particular definition where in your proposed reasoning you move from something that is _true_ about $E=(0,1]$ to something that is _false_ about $E=(0,1]$.

Comment: In fact, the (BW) property stands : "an infinite set **has** a cluster point" (to me, the difference is not significant from French but I do it more precisely now).
So the reasoning is : "in $\mathbb{R}$, the collection of all infinite bounded sets verifies the (BW) property; since this property is equivalent to the (BL) property and since this one means compactness, all infinite bounded sets is compact". Which is false. My question remains.

Comment: @Carrérond: My confusion about what you mean by "verifies" remains, too.

Comment: OK, so: verify=satisfy=fulfil. Hence, for any infinite unbounded set $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$, there exists at least one real $r$ which is a cluster point of $E$ (which is true for instance for $]0,1]$). But we know that for any set of a metric space, the existence of a cluster point is equivalent that this set fulfils (BL) (any covering by open sets can be reduced to a finite covering...). So $E$ fulfils (BL), and so is compact (which is false for $]0,1]$).

Comment: @Carrérond: Are you _completely sure_ that the property you're talking about doesn't require $r$ to be a member of $E$ itself? Can you quote and cite the exact definition you're working from, please?

Comment: In particular, I would expect the definition to be something like "$E$ has the BW property iff for every infinite $A\subseteq E$ there is an $r\in E$ that is a cluster point of $A$". And $E=(0,1]$ does _not_ have that property, because the only cluster point of, say, $A=\{\frac1n\mid n\in\mathbb N_+\}$ is not in $E$.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to Henning Makholm, I realized my mistake. 
The definition of a cluster point refers to a subset $E$ of a topological space $X$, whereas the notion of compactness refers to the topology in itself, i.e. $E$ is a compact set ("of $X$") if and only if it is compact as a topological space for the topology of subspace. Hence, for compactness, the (BW) property must be studied from the viewpoint of the topological space, and not from the viewpoint of $E$ being a subset of $X$.

For example, in $X=\mathbb{R}$, it is true that any infinite subset of $E=]0,1]$ has a cluster point **in $X$**, even the infinite subset $A=\{\frac{1}{n} / n\in\mathbb{N^*}\}$ which has $0$ as cluster point in $X$. So $E$ verifies in $X$ the property that lies in (BW), but $E$ is not compact (or "is not a compact subset of $X$") because as a topological space, $E$ doesn't fulfil (BW) since the infinite set $A$ has no cluster point **in $E$**.

Comment: No this doesn't convince me at all. This stuff with the viewpoint you wrote in the first paragraph doesn't make any sense to me. Clusterpoint and compactness are both properties depending on the topology/subspacetopology.

Comment: Can you be more precise and tell what doesn't convince you, please? To me, things are now clear an I can go on my discovery...

Comment: The first paragraph looks fine and correct to me.